# Merge the [Opengraph] and [Facebook-opengraph]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Can [opengraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengraph) or [facebook-opengraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph) be an synonym of the other?

Somebody added a [Synonym request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opengraph/synonyms)

Comment: I would appreciate this. I was just about to suggest it.

Comment: Even though I don't normally like tag prefixes, I resolved in favor of [[tag:facebook-opengraph]] being the "master" tag, since that one is officially sponsored by Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tags seem to be synonym to me:

- [open-graph-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-graph-protocol):

  > The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object in a social graph. Web pages become open graph objects by adding basic metadata information to a page. The projects web page is located at http://ogp.me.
- [opengraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengraph):

  > Facebook's Graph API allows websites to draw information about more objects than simply people, including photos, events, and pages, and their relationships between each other. This expands the social graph concept to more than just relationships between individuals and instead applies it to virtual non-human objects between individuals, as well.
  >
  > #### External links
  >
  > - http://ogp.me/
  > - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/
- [facebook-opengraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph):

  > The Facebook Open Graph allows apps to model user activities based on actions and objects and to become part of the user's identity and social graph. Building an Open Graph app gives you the opportunity to deeply integrate into the core Facebook experience, including Timeline, News Feed, and Ticker.
  >
  > - [Reference documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)
  > - [Open Graph Concepts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/)